# Why can sub-module names be accessed in __init__.py even without explicitly importing them?

Tags: python, python-import

The issue:

```
pkg/
    __init__.py
    sub1.py
    sub2.py


$ cat pkg/__init__.py
from .sub2 import *
print("init", dir())

$ cat pkg/sub1.py
from .sub2 import *
print("sub1", dir())

$ cat pkg/sub2.py
def spam():
    ...

$ python -c "import pkg"
init [... 'spam', 'sub2']

$ python -c "import pkg.sub1"
init [... 'spam', 'sub2']
sub1 [... 'spam']
```

Note how `sub2` is in the namespace of `pkg`, even though I don't actually import it. I would expect only the names inside `sub2` to be imported. Why is that not the case? I see that it has something to do with importing a package vs. importing a module, because:

```
$ python -c "import pkg.__init__"
init [... 'spam', 'sub2']
init [... 'spam']
```

It also seems to confuse `mypy`; I edit `__init__.py` to explicitly access `sub2`:

```
$ cat pkg/__init__.py
from .sub2 import *
print(sub2)
```

Then running `mypy pkg` gives:

```
pkg/__init__.py:2: error: Name "sub2" is not defined
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 3 source files)
```

Why is this happening? Is this a documented feature? I should note that this "feature" is used in the Cpython source; check, for example, `Lib/asyncio/__init__.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a quirk of submodules, but this is [documented behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules):

> When a submodule is loaded using any mechanism (e.g. `importlib` APIs,
> the `import` or `import-from` statements, or built-in `__import__()`) a
> binding is placed in the parent module’s namespace to the submodule
> object. For example, if package `spam` has a submodule `foo`, after
> importing `spam.foo`, `spam` will have an attribute `foo` which is bound to
> the submodule.

> ...

> Given Python’s familiar name binding rules this might seem surprising,
> but it’s actually a fundamental feature of the import system. The
> invariant holding is that if you have `sys.modules['spam']` and
> `sys.modules['spam.foo']` (as you would after the above import), the
> latter must appear as the foo attribute of the former.